# SearchView stops the application when no result found

Tags: java, android, sql-server, searchview

I have a search icon in the action bar of each screen.
It does find the items that exist in the database, however for items that does not exists, it doesn't show the message not

found. instead it the app stops. Do I have to add anything in manifest file? 
The php file returns echo "0"; if no result found.

searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

Each class "implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {" and have this code on it .

```
...
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }

     @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        String name=query;

        new Server(getBaseContext(),2,name.execute();

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }
...
```

and the specific part in the server class

```
protected String communicate(String argument1 ){
.....

 case 2: 
 link="...php";
                this.query=name;
                break;
.......
}

 protected void exec(String list){
...
 case 2:
                if (!found.equals("0")) {
                    String[] list = found.split(",");
                    String check="";
                    for (int i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
                        if (query.equals(list[i].toLowerCase())) check=list[i];
                    }


                    String name=check;

                    new Server(context,3,name).execute();
                }
                else Toast.makeText(context, "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try to add `try/catch` construction?

```
case 2:
   try {
         if (!found.equals("0")) {
                String[] list = found.split(",");
                String check="";
                for (int i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
                    if (query.equals(list[i].toLowerCase())) check=list[i];
                }


                String name=check;

                new Server(context,3,name).execute();
            }
       } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```